# Unity build freezes on gray screen after splash screen on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUvXY.png) I've been working on a game in Unity engine for the last week. Everything works fine on the Unity environment but when i build the .apk and run it on an android device it starts, shows the Unity splash screen, but then the screen stays gray (the same gray of the Unity splash screen) and doesn't do anything more. I've been doing some research on how to fix this but i couldn't find much info targeting this issue. I tried to run the adb logcat but i can't make it work. I am a total newbie about developing as you can see.

- I am using a Mac with OS 10.13.6 High Sierra.
- My Unity software is up to date.
- My phone is a Galaxy S9 and i enabled the developer features.
- The game shows no errors or warnings on the Unity console.

I will really appreciate any kind of help you can offer me.

Update: I tried running the game on my Android device via Unity Remote 5 and it works fine. But if i try running it from the apk file it freezes on the gray screen.

Comment: Have you included your game scenes in `Scenes In Build` in `Build Settings`?

Comment: Yes, it is automatically included and i double checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your build settings, have You add any open scenes..could you share as a screenshots of Your Build Settings and Configuration here, here might be help You http://answers.unity.com/answers/1423422/view.html

Comment: Hi! i've added a screenshot of the build settings. Everytime i build an apk i make sure that the scene is selected but is still showing the gray screen. I read the info on the link you shared but i couldn't find any "AppData" or "Roaming" folder.

Comment: then, You should check the Camera, whether it's behind Your target or canvas if You use any UI